# Excel 2010 Error message

Tags: microsoft-excel

Below is the formula I am using and I am getting the `#DIV/0!` error message because there is not any data in cell range `AE30:AQ30`, I can't figure out where in the below formula to put an `IFERROR` or an `ISERROR` which I believe would correct my error. Thoughts?

```
{=MOD(AVERAGE(IF(AE30:AQ30<>"",IF(AE30:AQ30<=TIME(12,0,0),1+AE30:AQ30,AE30:AQ30))),1)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to wrap the whole formula in an IFERROR, like:

```
=IFERROR(MOD(AVERAGE(IF(AE30:AQ30<>"",IF(AE30:AQ30<=TIME(12,0,0),1+AE30:AQ30,AE30:AQ30))),1),"Error")
```

You'd still confirm it with Ctrl+Shift+Enter

Answer (score 1):

You can write before Average Not(Iserror()) the result will be 0 the #DIV/0! error is the result of Avverage formula for empty cells, your formula will become:
`=MOD(Not(Iserror(AVERAGE(IF(AE30:AQ30<>"",IF(AE30:AQ30<=TIME(12,0,0),1+AE30:AQ30,AE30:AQ30))))),1)`
and use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Enter` for array formula